# ASP.NET Identity, how to change the view after successful authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I want to change the view after successful authorization (instead of default Index). My scenario is user (non authorized person) goes to main page (Index view) with Login button (generalized with ASP.NET Identity) on it. In the case user login as admin he should redirect to ANOTHER page (view, not Index) with another context on it. I use simple asp.net Identity functions (Account/Login) but I'm a begginer at Identity and can't get the right method to make changes what I need. How can I do it? What generalized method should I change just to make redirection for admin? Only what I've found is Ares.Identity.Pages.Account -> Login.cs

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is determining where you send the user on a successful login

```
returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
```

So if they try to access a secure page in your site, it will send them to the page they tried to access.  Otherwise is will send them to "~/" which is the root of your application.

Replace "~/" with the route you want to send them.

Comment: what route must be like? Ok, f.e. my next view after redirection ill be "Admin View". What should I write between " " in this case?

Comment: what is the url of your admin view?

Comment: I've found what I  need: returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/Home/AdminView/"); Thanks a lot!